# Making a databaseDo() function for hooking PDO queries

Tags: php, function, pdo

So I started [this tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#7.1) as an intro to the PHP PDO. Up until now I've only worked with basic `mysql_*` type queries.

I've noticed that, throughout the tutorial, the `connect -> do action -> disconnect` pattern is repeated, and only the `do action` part ever changes.

In a real-world setting, would it be a good idea to eliminate repetition by creating a function into which queries can be passed?

For example:

### a function for handling queries:

```
<?php
function databaseDo($action) {
    $db_hostname = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'root';
    $db_password = 'root';

    try {
        // Establish DB connection
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", 
                $db_username, $db_password);
        echo 'Connected to database';

        // Do something
        $action($dbh);        // <- here goes whatever action we wish to perform

        // Close connection
        $dbh = null;
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Then, suppose I want to perform the action in the first example of the PDO tutorial, I would set it like this:

```
<?php
// Define action
$insert = function($dbh) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO animals(animal_type, animal_name)
                VALUES ('kiwi', 'troy')";
    $exec = $dbh->exec($query);
    echo $exec; 
};

// Perform action
databaseDo($insert);
?>
```

### Scope of $dbh

I am using $dbh as an argument. Is this the proper way of passing a variable to a function like this without making it global?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is a great idea
A suggestion would be making a database helper class that uses the singleton pattern.. Something like

```
abstract class DB
   {

    protected static $instance;

    protected $db;

    protected static $host = 'host';
    protected static $user = 'user';
    protected static $pass = 'pass';
    protected static $database;

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) self::$instance = new static();

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function doStatement($statement, array $parameters)
    {

         $handler = self::sql()->prepare($statement);
         $handler->closeCursor();
         $handler->execute($parameters);
         return $handler;
    }
    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s', static::$host, static::$database), static::$user, static::$pass);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    }

    public static function db()
    {
        return static::getInstance()->db;
    }
}

class Main extends DB
{
    protected static $database = 'db';
}
```

to use it

```
$db = Main::getInstance();
$results = $db::doStatement('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = :id', array(':id' => 5));
```

Now this is just very basic, and much more would need to be added (Exception handling, more/better helper methods, etc) but I have used something like this in many projects.

Comment: cool. I've only just started looking at OOP stuff so I've not yet had a chance to use it.

Answer (score 1):

While avoidance of repetition (DRY) is a principle that should always factor into your coding decisions, it should be achieved without violating another important principle, which is the separation of concerns ([SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), see also [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Your example, databaseDo($action), is dual-purpose: it (1) instantiates a database connection and (2) it executes a query.

Now, you may say, 'Yes! That is just what I want! Kill two birds with one stone!', and your reason for saying so would be understandable. However, mixing responsibilities can become problematic because, when you have to make changes to the way in which one responsibility is handled, you will likely also have to make changes to the way the other responsibility is handled.

Imagine you were, at some point down the road, required to support two database connections instead of just one. Suppose one of the two databases supports transactions on tables for which the other does not. Your databaseDo() function will first have to negotiate to which database to connect, and then, in order to safely execute the 'do' action, some transaction support testing will be required. It would look something like this:

```
$context = 'production'; // but it could equally be 'development'

function databaseDo($action) {
  $db_hostname = ($context == 'production') ? 'http://remotehost.com' : 'localhost';
  $db_username = ($context == 'production') ? 'apache' : 'root';
  $pass = ($context == 'production') ? 'productionpassword' : 'developmentpassword';

  try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=mysql", $db_username, $db_password);
    echo 'Connected to database';

    if($context == 'production') {
      // ... some complicated logic to determine whether the production db 
      // will support your query, then execute it if so, exit if not ... 
    }

    if($context == 'development') {
      // ... some more complicated logic for testing and querying the 
      // development db ...
    }

    $dbh = null;
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Additional requirements for handling one responsibility will add complexity to the handling of the second responsibility, and this function will become more and more difficult to maintain.

A better approach to DRY in this scenario would be to handle database connection management in one component, such as within a context-aware singleton class instance (a common approach), and the query handling in another component. Thus, your query function would not necessarily have to change on account of a change in database connection handling. The tutorial to which you referred has [instructions for creating and using such a singleton instance](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#13).